# Drush error after Yosemite update

Tags: osx-yosemite, drush

I just updated to Yosemite and I keep getting this error message from drush.

> dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.53.dylib
>   Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/php   Reason: image not found
>   /usr/local/Cellar/drush/HEAD/libexec/drush: line 124: [: -le: unary
>   operator expected Execute a drush command. Run `drush help [command]`
>   to view command-specific help.  Run `drush topic` to read even more
>   documentation.

I installed this with brew and it's up to date has far has I know.  Has anyone else received this error message?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

make this steps:

```
brew reinstall pcre && brew unlink pcre && brew link pcre
brew reinstall php55
brew link php55
brew uninstall drush
brew install --HEAD drush
```

= it works.

Answer (score 3):

```
brew reinstall php55
```

Should work. Did for me.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this issue when trying to just run a simple php script. If you look in /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/, you will probably notice that libicui18n.53.dylib doesn't exist anymore and is now named libicui18n.54.dylib. My guess is PHP was compiled with the old library libicui18n.53.dylib and since it no longer is there, it complains. (I ran the command brew upgrade, which upgraded the libicu to version 54)

The way I fixed this, was by upgrading my php (which in turn, recompiled it). In my case, it was:

```
brew upgrade php55
```

Once it completed upgrading, the error no longer appeared, and I was able to run php scripts again.

Hope this helps you, as I know my fix was specific to my machine.

Answer (score 0):

I have this error after update from Maverick 10.9 to Yosemite 10.10. I fix this issue follow this article: [Get Apache, MySQL, PHP and phpMyAdmin working on OSX 10.10 Yosemite](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-working-osx-10-10-yosemite)

> With Apples’ new OSX 10.10 Yosemite out of the bag, getting the AMP
> stack up and running on the new OSX may cause a few bumps on the
> upgrade from OS X Mavericks 10.9. This tutorial will go through the
> process on getting Apache, MySQL, PHP (or otherwise known as the ‘AMP’
> stack) and phpMyAdmin running on the new Yosemite OS.

And overwrite php5.4 (Maverick version) via:

```
brew link --overwrite php55
```

Answer (score 0):

For me none of the above worked for me. I finally found a solution on Github.

I had the same issue after upgrading OSX to Yosemite. I kept getting the following error:

> Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) the Drupal database.

I thought it was a mysql problem, but the following worked for me: I edited my `~/.bash_profile` once again, adding these lines:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.4.4/bin:$PATH"

export PATH
export DRUSH_PHP="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/bin/php"
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Restart the terminal and voila - drush works like a charm again. [Thanks to C13L0.](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/512)

Answer (score 0):

```
brew uninstall php55 
brew install php55
```

"brew reinstall php55" didn't work for me. not sure why, but typing the commands separately did.